# Foreground MediaBrowserService is killed on app exit

Tags: android, mediabrowserservicecompat

I'm following the [Android guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/building-a-mediabrowserservice) to use MediaBrowserServiceCompat in a media player app, but the service is destroyed on app exit.

```
    <service android:name=".media.PlaybackService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

On application start service is created correctly. On button pressed `mediaController.transportControls.play()` is called and after this `onPlay()` method from my session callback class is invoked. Inside `onPlay()` service is started: `context.startService(Intent(context, MediaBrowserServiceCompat::class.java))` (also tried `startForegroundService` for Oreo and higher) and set to foreground: `this@PlaybackService.startForeground(SERVICE_ID, notificationBuilder?.build())`. Notification channel for Oreo nad higher API is created.

For now notification is launched and I can see service is in foreground by issuing command:

> ```
> $adb shell dumpsys activity services PlaybackService
> (...)
> isForeground=true foregroundId=1 foregroundNoti=Notification(channel=MyChannelId pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x62 color=0xff000000 category=transport actions=1 vis=PUBLIC)
> (...)
> ```

So far everything works fine but when I press home button I'm expecting the service remain started, but instead the `onDestroy()` method of my `MediaBrowserServiceCompat` class is invoked. After returning to the app and launching service once again it is not set to foreground (no notification as well).

I'm using the only one `startService` call in my app and removed every call to `stopSelf` and `stopForeground` for testing.

On APIs 28, 26, 22 and 18 I'm getting the same result.

I've also tried returning `START_STICKY` from `onStartCommand()`.

Comment: Did you figure out what was the issue? I am running into the exact same problem and it would be great to know what you have done. Google's documentation is just horrible regarding MediaBrowserService and all it's intricacies

Comment: Unfortunately, I've had no time to refine this hobby project, so I've put up with UX degradation.

Comment: @RikvanVelzen Did you figure it out? I am stuck with the same issue, and have not been able to find any relevant documentation

Answer (score 0):

It may certainly be that your `MediaBrowser` connection was the only thing keeping the `MediaBrowserService` going and closing that connection causes the `MediaBrowserService` to be destroyed.

In my case, I decided to create the service before the creation of the `MediaBrowser`:

```kotlin
// Create the media browser service
Intent intent = new Intent(application, MusicService.class);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    context.startForegroundService(intent);
} 
else {
    context.startService(mixerIntent);
}

// Create connection with the service
mediaBrowser = MediaBrowserCompat(
        context,
        ComponentName(requireContext(), MusicService::class.java),
        connectionCallbacks,
        null
)
```

Don't forget: once the service has been created, the service must call its `startForeground` method within five seconds.